# Validation in javascript for asp.net tree node

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a program with a tree control to assign user permissions like student can access only attendance and staff can assign attendance to students and so on...

I want to validate this with javascript to see that if no checkbox in tree is selected or all nodes in a tree is deselected or left empty ..i have to throw a validation error using javascript. I have attached by design coding and js coding i have used until now.

i tried the regular checkboxes validtion and it does not produce any result. Please help me

**Javascript**

```
function AreAllSiblingsChecked(chkBox)
   {
     var parentDiv = GetParentByTagName("div", chkBox);
     var childCount = parentDiv.childNodes.length;
     for(var i=0; i<childCount; i++)
     {
        if(parentDiv.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) //check if the child node is an element node
        {
            if(parentDiv.childNodes[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "table")
            {
               var prevChkBox = parentDiv.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
              //if any of sibling nodes are not checked, return false
              if(!prevChkBox.checked) 
              {
                return false;
              } 
            }
        }
     }
     return true;
   }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Code would help - specifically, the HTML of the tree, the javascript you have tried and any other code that you think can help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly set a class name of the elements you want to check and then use jquery api and selectors to get checked elements.

Have a look at the api documentation of jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/